# Why opacity is 0, but my if statement still execute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, opacity

I got a question on my codes.

I use `$(this).css('opacity')` to check if an element is transparent or not. When the element is transparent, it should return 0.

However, `if( $(this).css('opacity') !== 0 )` executes when it returns 0. Any idea why this happens?

Thanks in advance!

My codes is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/dennisboys/f3JuH/2/

Comment: CSS values are always strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because a CSS value is always returned as a string (unlike the `height` and `width` jQuery methods, which return a number).

Try if this test works for you:

```
if( parseFloat($(this).css('opacity')) !== 0 )
```

or simply use a weak (type-coercing) inequality:

```
if( $(this).css('opacity') != 0 )
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS values returns as string.   change condition like this.

```
if( $(this).css('opacity') !== "0" )
```

or

```
if(parseFloat($(this).css('opacity'))!==0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse that value first.so your if will be.

```
if(parseFloat($(this).css('opacity'))!==0)
```

**[And the workin demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f3JuH/8/)**

**Edit:parseInt to parseFloat**

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the condition is true indeed. The .css('opacity') returns a string; so in your case it will return '0' which is of course different from the number 0 since you' re using the not identically equal operator (!==).

You should probably use the not equal operator (!=).

'0' !== 0 --> true
'0' != 0 --> false